# Jquery - Get attribute value of closest class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to grab the attribute value from the closest element with the class specified but keep getting back undefined.

Below is my HTML and my code, I am not too sure what am doing wrong to get back undefined.

**HTML**

```
    <body>
  <form action="/update" id="formwrite">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title va-middle">Account Settings
                        <img src='../images/colopen.svg' data-swap='../images/coll.svg' class="panel-icon collapse-icon" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collaspeOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collaspeOne">
                        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collaspeOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-default">
            <div class="row fieldpos">
              <fieldset class="form-group textwide">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title va-middle">Other Settings
                                <img src='../images/colopen.svg' data-swap='../images/coll.svg' class="panel-icon collapse-icon" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collaspeTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collaspeTwo">
                                </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collaspeTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="panel-default">
            <div class="row fieldpos">
              <fieldset class="form-group textwide">
                <label for="group">Test</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="group" placeholder="test" required>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control savechanges">Save Changes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success form-control test">Call Function</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).on("click", ".test", function (){
    $("input[required]").each(function(){
    var inputval = $(this).val();
    var collaspe = $(this).closest(".collapse-icon").attr("aria-expanded");
    console.log(collaspe);
        if(!inputval){
            console.log("Required Empty");
            $(".collapse-icon").trigger("click");
        } else {
            console.log("Required has value");;
        }
    });
    });
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycfpe5zd/2/)

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: closest travels up the DOM (through parents), but your input elements don't have any parent elements with the "collapse-icon" class - these appear to be in siblings of the parents.  You'll probably have to go up to the parent "collapse", then to its previous sibling, then down the dom from there to the collapse icon.

Comment: Quick note about your HTML: your second collapse panel is not part of the `.panel-group[role='tablist']` which means the second panel can be open the same time as your first panel. If that's the intention, then my comment is pointless; however if you want an accordion panel group then that second panel needs to be nested :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up the DOM searching only ancestors, it will not search for the "literal" closest element. Your `.collapse-icon` don't appear to be direct parents, but rather are children of the `.panel-heading` elements (which are parents). So the solution would be `$(this).closest('.panel-heading').find('.collapse-icon')`

**UPDATE**: I apologize, in my answer I mispoke. It should be `.closest('.panel').find('.panel-heading .collapse-icon')` since `.panel-heading` is a sibling of the or input's parent. So you need the `.panel-body`'s parent and then find it's heading collapse icon.

Comment: Still returning undefined as seen here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycfpe5zd/2/)

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest the $(".collapse-icon").trigger("click") in the JS would need updating, as that'll trigger all the elements with that class.

Comment: My bad I removed the panels within the panels and it now works!

Answer (score 0):

As already explained closest only search in direct ancestors.

Here is a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z5wbxzzo/2/

```
  $(document).on("click", ".test", function (){
    $("input[required]").each(function(){
    var inputval = $(this).val();
    var collaspe = $(this).closest(".panel-collapse").siblings(".panel-heading").find(".collapse-icon").attr("aria-expanded");
    console.log(inputval, collaspe);
        if(!inputval){
            console.log("Required Empty");
            $(".collapse-icon").trigger("click");
        } else {
            console.log("Required has value");;
        }
    });
    });
```

hope this helps

Comment: The problem with this answer is `$.find()` may locate an incorrect element. For example, if you click the second element and it traverses up to the panel group, `$.find(".collapse-icon")` could find the first collapse icon and not the second

Comment: Have updated please check. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Makes sense! Assuming there aren't multiple panel headings siblings (which based on the given HTML there aren't)

Comment: Hope i could be some help :)

Answer (score 0):

closest() return the first ancestor matching the specified selector.

.collapse-icon is not an ancestor of input[required]

As I guess there is more than one .panel element in a .panel-group you will have to identify first the top .panel element (by an id or a specific class name or whatever) next dive into it to find the .collapse-icon

html code

```
<div class="panel panel-container">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title va-middle">Account Settings
            <img src='../images/colopen.svg' data-swap='../images/coll.svg' class="panel-icon collapse-icon" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collaspeOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collaspeOne">
        </h4>
    </div>

    ...
```

js code

```
$(this).closest('.panel-container').find('.collapse-icon')
```